# Chain of responsibility with async await method and exception handling in C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have some async and await method; if an error occurs, instead of throwing an error, it just exits the handler and continues processing the rest of the methods in that service for example this is the handler.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chain.Of.Responsibility.Example.Chain.Pattern
{
    public abstract class Handler<T>
    {
        private IHandler<T> Next { get; set; }

        public virtual async Task Handle(T request)
        {
            Next?.Handle(request);
        }

        public IHandler<T> SetNext(IHandler<T> next)
        {
            Next = next;
            return Next;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the `UsernameRequiredValidationHandler`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chain.Of.Responsibility.Example.Chain.Pattern
{
    public class UsernameRequiredValidationHandler : Handler<User>, IHandler<User>
    {
        public override async Task Handle(User user)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Username))
            {
                throw new Exception("Username is required.");
            }

            base.Handle(user);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `PasswordRequiredValidationHandler`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chain.Of.Responsibility.Example.Chain.Pattern
{
    public class PasswordRequiredValidationHandler : Handler<User>, IHandler<User>
    {
        public override async Task Handle(User user)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Password))
            {
                throw new Exception("Password is required.");
            }

             base.Handle(user);
        }
    }
}
```

This is `OnlyAdultValidationHandler`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Chain.Of.Responsibility.Example.Chain.Pattern
{
    public class OnlyAdultValidationHandler : Handler<User>, IHandler<User>
    {
        public override async Task Handle(User user)
        {
            throw new Exception();

            if (user.BirthDate.Year > DateTime.Now.Year - 18)
            {
                throw new Exception("Age under 18 is not allowed.");
            }

            base.Handle(user);
        }
    }
}
```

When exception is thrown in `OnlyAdultValidationHandler`, it is not caught in `try catch` block in the `Register` class

```
public class ChainPatternRegistrationProcessor
{
        public async Task Register(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                var handler = new UsernameRequiredValidationHandler();
                handler.SetNext(new PasswordRequiredValidationHandler())
                    .SetNext(new OnlyAdultValidationHandler());

                await handler.Handle(user);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
}
```

Can we catch this error in the `Register` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `await` in the `abstract class Handler<T>` in mehtod `Handle`:

> await Next?.Handle(request);

Now when an exception will be thrown the stack will be properly constructed and the `try` `catch` from `Register` will get it.

**Update**

As Klaus suggested you will have to add `await` also on `base.Handle(user)`.

Comment: Also, it should be `await base.Handle(user)` (or `return base.Handle(user)` when omitting the `async`).